# Does $m(\{x: |f| >n \} ) \to 0$ if $f$ is $m$-a.e. finite?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, m)$ be a measure space with $\sigma$-finite measure $m$. Let $f$ be a measurable, real-valued function.

Does $m(\{x: |f| >n \} ) \to 0$ if $f$ is $m$-a.e. finite?

I think this is true but I am having difficulty with a function begin a.e. bounded versus a.e. finite, and am looking to understand the properties of an a.e. finite function on a $\sigma$-finite measure space.

Comment: How about the example $f(x) = x$ on $\Bbb{R}$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: It is true with the additional hypothesis that $m(\{x : |f(x)| > n\})$ is finite for some $n$, because $A_n = \{x : |f(x)| > n\}$ is a decreasing nested sequence of sets with $m\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\right) = m(\{x : |f(x)| = \infty\}) = 0$.

Comment: @SangchulLee great counter-example, thanks!

Comment: @Bungo this is useful to know, I will keep it in mind!