# On the existence of the essential supremum

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. If $f$ is a real-valued, measurable, and a.e. finite function, does it have a finite essential supremum?

My intuition says not necessarily, as the essential supremum is equal to: $$\inf \left\{ a \geq 0:  \mu(\{x: |f(x)| > a\}) = 0\right\}$$ and from a question I asked yesterday [(here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477249/does-m-x-f-n-to-0-if-f-is-m-a-e-finite) it seems there are examples where the value is infinite for the conditions above.

If my intuition is correct, then is the article [here](http://planetmath.org/proofofexistenceoftheessentialsupremum) proving that the essential supremum exists although it could be infinite?

Any clarification on this topic would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: The function $f(x) =1/x$ defined on the unit interval $X=(0,1)$  with $\mu$ equal to  Lebesgue measure  is everywhere finite but not essentially bounded, because $\mu(\{x\in(0,1):|f(x)|>a\})=\min(1/a,1)>0$ for all $a>0$.

The planetmath.org article you cite concerns a different kind of essential supremum: there is a collection $\{f_i:i\in I\}$ of measurable functions on $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ and one seeks a measurable function $f$ such that (i) $f\ge f_i$, $\mu$-a.e, for each $i\in I$, and (ii) if $f'$ is any other measurable function with property (i) then $f\le f'$, $\mu$-a.e.